# How can I test this method?

Tags: c#, wcf

This is my web service method

```
public string PostAllSurveyList(List<Survey> surveyList)
{
    var surveyDbList = ConstructDbServeyList(surveyList);
    foreach (var survey in surveyDbList)
    {

        _db.surveys.Add(survey);
    }
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return "Successfully Saved";
}
```

How can I test it from the vs2010 deuging tool. How can I give this list as parameter.

[image]

Comment: I think this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788214/how-to-specify-list-parameters-in-wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe

Comment: I found a Firefox plugin that I found more useful for testing REST API's. It has more features than the VS tool, although I'm not 100% sure it can do what you want. Just thought I'd mention it https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/