# Invoke method using WcfTestClient

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm new to WCF and I'm trying to invoke a method using WCF test client.
The method signature looks like this.

```
void AddToRole(String roleName, IEnumerable<RoleMemberInfo> UserOrGroups)
```

Im not sure what to pass as a value for the second parameter while invoking using the WcfTestClient. Is it even possible to invoke it from the TestClient?

I mean, Simple intrinsic types are straight forward - just pass some value. But class types or more complex types, how can i pass an "instance" of such types as a parameter to the client?

Is my option limited to implementing a test client?

```
public class RoleMemberInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public String UserOrGroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String DirectoryService { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you "know" the class RoleMemberInfo? Do you have metadata of it? The method seems pretty straightforward to me. Pass a String and a IEnumerable of RoleMemberInfo...You should know more about the context of the method.

Comment: Have updated the post with the roleMemberInfo class. This is my first time using the tool for more complex types. Am still not sure what and how to pass something as second parameter in the WcfTestClient.

Comment: After a lot of searching I bumped into this. Its simple once you know how. Until then, you are pretty much clueless. The designers of the tool were obviously unawre of tooltips!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788214/how-to-specify-list-parameters-in-wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
public void UseWCFMethod()
{
  String roleName = "Admin";

  RoleMemberInfo info = new RoleMemberInfo();
  info.UserOrGroupId = "1";
  info.DirectoryService = "Default";

  wcfProxy.AddToRole(roleName, info);
}
```

I just defined some random values for the variables. I assume you know the meaning of those variables in their context. Let me state it this way, you know what service you are consuming and what functionality it has, what it does, where it comes from, who produced it, etc.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I was looking for. I was trying to invoke using the WcfTestClient. I am aware that I can write a client in C# and invoke using that. I am trying to understand how to invoke using the WcfTestClient